# Cannot load photo locally in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

So, i am creating an ASP.NET(MVC5) application, on which i want to show an image using an `img` tag like that:

```
<img src='@Url.Content(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Products-Data"), product.Name, product.ThumbnailImage))' />
```

The problem is that no browser actually load the image. The fun thing is that the link generated by the razor engine is valid, and i can see the image if i open it from another browser tab. After some searching i noticed that in the chrome console, there was this error:

[image]

I found a lot of topics regarding this error(change settings in web.config, use the --allow-file-access-from-files flag and e.t.c), but none of these actually worked. This is going to be a real-world application ... but for the time being i need to test it locally, and check if everything works properly. Any work around's here folks ?

Comment: Take ur photo address within your controller then send it using a viewbag or something, then you trace the issue within controller.

Comment: Why are you using paths that refer to the local file system? Why not an HTTP(S) URL?

Comment: do not use `Server.MapPath` for a virtual path that will be resolved on the client (in the browser). Just use the virtual path. `Url.Content` already takes care of any necessary path mapping/rooting. No difference between development environment and production environment here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to generate the path using relative path, resolving it to the absolute path wouldn't work, as it will be the path of the server's particular drive location which is most of the times outside of the working directory of the web application and it is not possible for the browser to fetch the resource using physical path, so it wouldn't work for you.

You would need to do do it something like :

```
<img src="@Url.Content(String.Format("~/Products-Data/{0}/{1}", product.Name, product.ThumbnailImage))" />
```

and it would be more better if you pass it via **Model** object the relative path and the view just have displaying code, view should not contain logic to generate the path.

Hope it helps you!